# How can I write conditions for data-ng-disabled in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How can I write conditions for data-ng-disabled in Angularjs:

The button should only be enabled in the following scenarios:

1: The slot should be selected and check if selected slot margin is <=35 and Reason != ‘’

2: The slot should be selected and the check if the margin is >35

The code that I tried but it doesn't work:

```js
data-ng-disabled="!selAppt.selected && (selAppt.selected.margin >= 35 || ReservedAssessorDetails != '')"
```

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean?  did you get an unexpected result? did you get an error message?  did something else happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of the reason why it appears to be failing is that `!selAppt.selected` and `selAppt.selected.margin` will never return true when utilized together.  So your conditional will only render true when you have no selected appointment **AND** the reserved assessor detail is not *falsy*.  So you need to fix that logic first.

Secondly, I'd write a filter for this:

```
.filter( 'hasSelected', [
    function(){
        return function(selAppt, ReservedAssesorDetail){
            return conditional-based-on-logic
        }
    }
])
```

then you implement like so:

```
<elem ng-disabled="selAppt | hasSelected : ReservedAssesorDetail"/>
```

The reason I advocate a filter over an inline solution is that if for some reason the conditional logic changes, you need only change it in the filter once, rather than how ever many times you've written it inline.